# how to copy folder in cloudme programmatically

Tags: iphone, cloud, directory, copy-paste, webdav

i want to make my iphone app can connect to some webdav server using flycode in [this site](https://github.com/ccgus/flycode/tree/master/WebDAV) , i've done with all implementation, but i have problem in copying folder in [cloudme server](http://www.cloudme.com/). I dont have this problem in another webdav server. The response code i have in this process is 403, and the response strings are :

response string :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 403 COPY needs a file as source</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /myApp/xios/Documents/myDirectory///. Reason:
<pre>    COPY needs a file as source</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>



</body>
</html>
```

this is the code that i use to called copy method in flying code webdav :

```
NSURL *urlFrom = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"https" host:[prefs objectForKey:@"idiskhost"] path:fromPath];

    NSURL *urlTo = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"https" host:[prefs objectForKey:@"idiskhost"] path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",forPath]];

[[[MyAppWebDAVRequest requestToURL:urlFrom] synchronous] copyToDestinationURL:urlTo];
```

did cloudme support for copy folder? or am i did something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this case, the problem is CloudMe didn't give any permission to copy a folder, I now this from the system response log.